# SQL How to order logged data according to the date and the user?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where I need to create an ordered "event" or "touch" ranking based on the date and the user that touched a case from a historical log table. For example, I have a log table that looks like this:

```
case_id  user_id  log_date
-------  -------  --------
1        5        06-29 12:05
1        5        06-29 12:10
1        5        06-30 9:12
1        3        06-30 9:15
```

And I want to get this:

```
case_id  user_id  log_date     EventNumber
-------  -------  --------     -----------
1        5        06-29 12:05  1
1        5        06-29 12:10  1
1        5        06-30 9:12   2
1        3        06-30 9:15   3
```

Basically either a change in the date or a change in the user that touched a case signifies that a new event has occurred. The closest I got so far is `[EventNum] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY case_id ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, log_date), user_id)`

The problem with this approach is that the secondary order, while correctly incrementing the rank number because a different user touched it would put the second user first because the user_id happens to be a lower number. I can't figure out how to "partition" by users while maintaining the original logged order. Even the date break part isn't essential - I would settle breaking up the ranking only by users provided the original logged order remains the same. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question.  You need to identify groups where the date *and* user are adjacent.  One method is to use `lag()`.  But, not available in SQL Server 2008.  Another method is to use a difference of row numbers.

The difference defines the group.  You then need to get the minimum date for the final ordering.  So:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by caseid order by grp_log_date) as EventNum
from (select t.*, min(log_date) over (partition by caseid, grp) as grp_log_date
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by caseid order by log_date) -
                    row_number() over (partition by caseid, userid, cast(log_date) as date
                                       order by log_date
                                      )
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
      ) t;
```